# IOS trigger notification action when app is in the background

Tags: ios, notifications

My app does the following when the app is opened from a remote notification. Basically, it saves `article_id` in `UserDefaults` so that I can use it when the app is launched:

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(
        _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
        didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void
    ) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        
        if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject] {

            let article_id = aps["article_id"]
            UserDefaults.standard.set(article_id, forKey: "notification_article_id")
        }

        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

However, this only works if the app is completely closed. If the app remains in the background and the user clicks the notification (e.g. from the lock screen), the function above will not be triggered. Thus, it will not save the data into my `UserDefaults`. Does any one know how to trigger a similar action in this situation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your extension delegate function declaration is correct, and should fire in the state that you described (lock screen, home screen, app backgrounded). Please make sure that you have set the delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

}
```

If this is already set, I would verify that your parsing code is correct, and test on the simulator or another device. I often use xcrun simctl to test push notifications in the simulator. You can do this by creating a dummy test file called 'payload.json', and exectuting the following command in the terminal:

```
xcrun simctl push booted com.yourapp.bundle.id payload.json
```

This is an example of a payload.json:

```
{
    "Simulator Target Bundle": "com.yourapp.bundle.id",
    "aps":{
        "alert":{
            "title":"Egon Spengler",
            "body":"I collect spores, molds, and fungus"
        },
        "sound":"alert.caf",
        "badge":3
    },
    "alert":{
        "alertUuid":"asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf",
        "state":1,
        "lastUpdate":"2020-11-8T21:43:57+0000"
    }
}
```

If the application has been terminated, you can obtain notification content at launch using the following code within *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*:

```
 let notificationOption = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification]
 if let notification = notificationOption as? [String: AnyObject] {
           
 }
```

Finally, make sure that you have enabled 'Remote Notifications' background mode in your project settings:

[image: Background Modes]

Comment: Thanks, I have set `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self`, and my code works if the app is opened (not activated from background) from notification. The problem is that, if the app is already in the background of the phone, the function will not be called. Because the app is not "launched", but reactivated.

Comment: @OUO is the app backgrounded or terminated? I have added code to handle the notification if the app has been terminated. Please give this a try.

Comment: I was asking about backgrounded app. So, the app is not terminated. It was in the background. For example, when the user locked the screen without terminating the app, or opened another app when my app is still in the background.

Comment: @OUO Under the 'Signing and Capabilities' tab of TARGETS in your project config, you will see a section called 'Background Modes'. Check 'Background Fetch' and 'Remote Notifications'. I am assuming you have already added Push Notifications to your capabilities.